# Connecting to MySQL Database on Windows using C++ fails on connect under general exception with bad allocation

Tags: c++, mysql

I am currently learning C++ which isn't going overly smoothly. I am doing a test with a small, simple app, connecting to a MySQL Database.

Below is my main method

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    DBConnectionManager dbConnManager;
    dbConnManager.performSql();

    return 0;
}
```

Below is my DBConnectionManager header file

```
#ifndef MYSQLTEST_DBCONNECTIONMANAGER_H
#define MYSQLTEST_DBCONNECTIONMANAGER_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <exception.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <statement.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>

using namespace sql;

class DBConnectionManager
{
private:
    sql::Driver *driver = NULL;
    sql::Connection *conn = NULL;
    sql::Statement *statement = NULL;
    sql::ResultSet *res = NULL;
public:
    DBConnectionManager();
    void performSql();
};
#endif //MYSQLTEST_DBCONNECTIONMANAGER_H
```

Below is my DBConnectionManager cpp constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DBConnectionManager.h"

using namespace std;

DBConnectionManager::DBConnectionManager() {
    cout << "Starting DBConnectionManager - Updated" << endl;
    try {
        cout << "Getting driver instance" << endl;
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        cout << "Got driver instance" << endl;
        conn = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "password");
        conn->setSchema("bugs");
        cout << "Connected to database" << endl;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        cout << "Error connecting to DB: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (exception ex) {
        cout << "Something has gone wrong: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Below is the output of my program

```
Hello World
Starting DBConnectionManager - Updated
Getting Driver Instance
Got Driver Instance
Something has gone wrong: bad allocation
```

### Update

I'm getting somewhere. I thought I needed to have `CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=;mysqlcppconn_EXPORT` set in the preprocessor

Now it seems to successfully connect so now when I try and read from the database it throws an error

Now I run a performQuery function in my DBConnectionManager which is as follows

```
void DBConnectionManager::performSql() {
    cout << "Going to perform query" << endl;
    try {
        if (conn == NULL)
        {
            cout << "conn is null" << endl;
            return;
        }
        statement = conn->createStatement();
        res = statement->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM reports");
        while (res->next()) 
        {
            string value = res->getString("Summary");
            cout << "ID: " << value << endl;
            cout << "-------------" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << "Finished Loop" << endl;

        delete res;
        delete statement;
        delete conn;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        cout << "Error executing query: " << ex.what() << "Error Code: " << ex.getErrorCode() << endl;
    }
    catch (exception ex) {
        cout << "Something unexpected went wrong in performSql:" << ex.what() << endl;
    }
```

When it runs `res->getString("Summary")` it doesn't throw the exception handler but Visual Studio pops up with the error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEEC421C80 (vcruntime140d.dll) in TestMySQL.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violating reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF`
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved finally.

I first of all thought that I needed `CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=;mysqlcppconn_EXPORT` to be set in the preprocessor. Turns out I don't which is why the get_driver_instance was failing.

The query issue calling res->getString() was crashing as you need to call c_str().
E.g.

`string value = res->getString("Summary").s_ctr()`